# jquery datatable with BootStrap ? mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I already developed my Jquery datatable now i want to apply BootStrap functionality to it .

I need to display columns variably depends upon view port say initially i am doing for desktop and tab .

My jquery datatable code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myDataTable').dataTable({

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
            "bJQueryUI": true,

            "aoColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "sName": "Lead_Id",
                                        "bVisible": false,
                                        "bSearchable": false,
                                        "bSortable": false
                                    },
                       {"sName": "Contact_Name"  }
                       },
                       { "sName": "Contact_Address" },
                       { "sName": "Lead_Source" },
                       { "sName": "Domain" }
            ]

        });
)};
```

HTML TABLE : // here i get mt data filled

```
<div id="demo">

    <table  id= "myDataTable" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
        <thead>        

            <tr>
                       <th>Lead Id</th>
                       <th>Contact Name</th>
                       <th>Contact Address</th>
                       <th>Lead Source</th>
                       <th>Domain</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

EDIT : IN the code mentioned i want to hide **Domain** which depends on VIEW PORT . how can i achieve this

EDIT 2 :

```
<tr class="odd" id="19">
<td class=" sorting_1">19</td>
<td class="">
<a href="Home/Details/19">Asadul Ltd</a>
</td>
<td class="">Hophouse</td>
<td class="" title="Click to select town">Essex</td>
</tr>
```

like this for every row with just change in data coming .. Now how to apply

EDIT 3:

```
<style>
.table-responsive tr td:nth-child(2)  {
visibility:hidden;
background: red;
position:absolute;

}
.table-responsive tr th:nth-child(2) {
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
background: white;
}
table#myDataTable tbody tr:nth-child(2) // i dont know what to do here
    {
        background: red;
    }

</style>
```

HERE i am trying with things i was successful applying background color white to the dynamically generated columns . but i dont know class="hidden-xs" which usually hides column variable based on view port size

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has responsive tables, you can use the classes of it like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Here are few examples:

http://jasonbradley.me/bootstrap-responsive-tables/

http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

You might also consider trying one of these approaches, since larger tables aren't exactly friendly on mobile even if it works:

http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

**Updated:**

you can add css class on `td` like this:

```
 $('#myDataTable').dataTable({

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
            "bJQueryUI": true,

            "aoColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "sName": "Lead_Id",
                                        "bVisible": false,
                                        "bSearchable": false,
                                        "bSortable": false
                                    },
                       {"sName": "Contact_Name"  },
                       { "sName": "Contact_Address"," sClass": "hidden-xs" },
                       { "sName": "Lead_Source", "sClass": "hidden-xs" },
                       { "sName": "Domain", "sClass": "hidden-xs" }
            ]

        });
```

Comment: what about hinding somecolumns mate ?

Comment: there are classes in bootstar for td that when you apply they go hidden on small screen size

Comment: yes i tried on <th> tag above its hiding  but under  <th> column data is not hinding mate becoz its getting dynamically loaded under TH tag . . is there any work around to hide the data i am getting via ajax call and sitting under respective TH tags ?? regards

Comment: you need to add class on them bootstrap provides calsses

Comment: yes i added but how to hide the dynamically getting column's .once plz check the above code in thead--tr TAGS .. i am having only th's . As you know ajaxsource will fill data . i appled css class 
<th class="hidden-xs">Contact Name</th> but it hides just the HEADING not the column data ..

Comment: Have you applied class on td as well? ?

Comment: there is no td in the above one . the jquery datatable plugin does the job of creating these td's . so is there anything possibly achieve this ?

Comment: Then you need to check in firebug what class is applied by plugin and add a css class with that name and write css that is applied on th,  then it will work

Comment: Mate i done debugging in chrome i found something and i am confused what to do . check edited my post . .HTML row posted .

Comment: here is class name odd you can use it or do like this:
table#myDataTable tbody td{} and app;y css

Comment: well there are odd and even class names i.e i believe those conventions are given based on id (even/odd) . . Other way you mentioned table#myDataTable tbody td{} ? ? i didn't get what exactly it means ? were should i use it ? ON td ? i need to apply on specific td say 2nd td in my each TR .

Comment: with your help i done something i can apply background color to dynamically generated columns but still main logic to get . posted edited added my work . share your views

Comment: finally i got the solution . Although its a one liner its been tough to get that . Just add this
 { "sName": "COMPANY_NAME", "sClass": "hidden-xs" } . . Please edit your answer with this code i can mark it as answer .

Comment: Thank you :0 learned a lot from this discussion ;) ty for your time